# converting byte array to double in lua

Tags: java, lua, redis, bit-manipulation

Redis (a key-value store) supports lua scripts - it executes the script on the server. I am interacting with Redis using a java client. I am passing a byte array to lua and in lua, I would have to convert that to a int or string.

The following is the java code snippet

```
byte[] exclScore = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putDouble(1.5).array();
args.add(exclScore);
```

args is an ArrayList of type byte[]

Following is the lua script that I tried

```
byteScore = table.remove(ARGV)
size = string.len(byteScore)
x = string.sub(byteScore,1,1)
local output = 0
for i = 1,size do
  bit = tonumber(string.sub(byteScore,i,1))
  val2 = bit * (2 ^ i)
  output = output + val2
end
return output
```

ARGV is the table which receives all the arguments sent by the java client and the score is the last entry. I checked the type(byteScore) and it turned out to be string. tonumber() returns a nil (which is the error I get, since I multiply it by 2)

Is there anyway in which we can convert this byte array into double or string representation of that double (1.5) in lua? Note that, we cannot use any external lua libraries inside redis scripts.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua is not a low-level language. It does not know how to handle byte arrays.

In theory, you could write a binary-to-double decoder (though that would be hard since Lua 5.1 doesn't have any bit manipulation stuff). But your time would be better spent trying to pass Lua data that is in a form Lua understands. Lua can convert strings to numbers, so you can pass Lua a string representation of that number.

Sanitize your data outside of Lua.

Comment: That seems to be the best option (sanitizing data outside lua). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue and found the solution after sometime, there was not much info on internet related to this I thought to update this thread

```
redis.call('zadd', KEYS[1], struct.unpack('>L', ARGV[1]), ARGV[2]);
```

You can use struct library to convert byte[] to Long, L here represents the unsigned byte and > represents the byte order (big endian).

for more info [https://github.com/iryont/lua-struct]

Answer (score 0):

What Nicol says is true. If you pass your double as a string: `"1.5"`, parsing it in your script is as simple as:

```
tonumber(table.remove(ARGV))
```

Comment: yes, that is true. But, all my other arguments are byte arrays, which is the reason for me to send the double as a byte array. If I have to convert this score to a string then I need to convert rest of the arguments to strings which I thought of avoiding. Since there is no choice, I might do that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your reason for sending the arguments as byte arrays?

Comment: The java client I use, to interact with Redis, converts all the arguments to byte arrays every time it passes data to Redis. Instead of this repetitive conversion, I do it only once and handle data as byte arrays all through my application.

Comment: But surely you don't have to do this parsing trickery with the client library by default? Are you using Jedis?

Comment: Yes, I am using Jedis. What are the other options?